# is differ between distributive lattice vs semi-lattice on Turing Degrees

Tags: logic, computability, lattice-orders, turing-machines

We know a Posed Closed under suprema but not necessarily under infima is an upper semi-lattice.

We now r.e set forms a distributive lattice.

But my question is why following statement is hold? I think the Turing degree is distributive lattice. I not need a formal proof, just some hint is enough.

> Turing Degrees $(D, \leq)$ under the partial order induced by Turing
>   Reducibility $\leq_T$ form only upper semi-lattice.

Comment: Could you edit the question to indicate *why* you think that the Turing degrees are a distributive lattice? Did you find that claim in a book or set of lecture notes?  Have you tried proving it?

Comment: @CarlMummer I think. maybe I wrong by lack of knowledge. would you please hint me?

Comment: I do self-study not in university. I read on https://books.google.com/books?id=9I7Pl00LU5gC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false page 31 @CarlMummert

Comment: From the second sentence of the question, I conjecture that you're conflating the poset of Turing degrees (partially ordered by Turing reducibility) and the lattice of r.e. set (partially ordered by inclusion).

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks, my problem is why $(D, \leq)$ cannot be distributive lattice?

Comment: As Carl Mummert explained in his answer, $(D,\leq)$ cannot be a distributive lattice because it is not a lattice; it has two elements with no greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard fact given as Corollary 4.4 on page 100 of Soare's book: there exists a pair of degrees with no greatest lower bound. All the details are provided there.

Comment: Thanks infact my problem is different. I it's enough to say there are degree b and c with no greatest lower bound to show $(D, \leq)$ form upper semi-lattice ? would you please answer my question as simple as possible, because I self-study. thanks

Comment: Wait ! what do you mean by upper semi-lattice ?

Comment: @nini: I have answered your question as simply as I am able: the reason that the degrees form only an upper semi-lattice is that they are an upper semi-lattice and there are some pairs of degrees with no greatest lower bound. I suggest that you continue your self study by carefully reading Soare's book, which will explain all these things in rigorous detail.

Comment: @user153695: that is standard terminology in the field.

Comment: +1. thanks I read it so well. my last question is can we say $(D, \leq)$ is disjunctive semi-lattice?